# Scipy's correlate function is slow

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have compared the different methods for convolving/correlating two signals using numpy/scipy. It turns out that there are huge differences in speed. I compared the follwing methods:

- correlate from the numpy package (np.correlate in plot)
- correlate from the scipy.signal package (sps.correlate in plot)
- fftconvolve from scipy.signal (sps.fftconvolve in plot)

Now I of course understand that there is a considerable difference between fftconvolve and the other two functions. What I do not understand is why the sps.correlate is so much slower than np.correlate. Does anybody know why scipy uses an implementation that is so much slower?

[image: Speed comparison]

For completeness, here is the code that produces the plot:

```
import time

import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sps

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = 10**(np.arange(10)/2)
    print(a)

    results = {}
    results['np.correlate'] = np.zeros(len(a))
    results['sps.correlate'] = np.zeros(len(a))
    results['sps.fftconvolve'] = np.zeros(len(a))

    ii = 0
    for length in a:

        sig = np.random.rand(length)

        t0 = time.clock()
        for jj in range(3):
            np.correlate(sig, sig, 'full')
        t1 = time.clock()
        elapsed = (t1-t0)/3

        results['np.correlate'][ii] = elapsed

        t0 = time.clock()
        for jj in range(3):
            sps.correlate(sig, sig, 'full')
        t1 = time.clock()
        elapsed = (t1-t0)/3

        results['sps.correlate'][ii] = elapsed

        t0 = time.clock()
        for jj in range(3):
            sps.fftconvolve(sig, sig, 'full')
        t1 = time.clock()
        elapsed = (t1-t0)/3

        results['sps.fftconvolve'][ii] = elapsed

        ii += 1

    ax = plt.figure()
    plt.loglog(a, results['np.correlate'], label='np.correlate')
    plt.loglog(a, results['sps.correlate'], label='sps.correlate')
    plt.loglog(a, results['sps.fftconvolve'], label='sps.fftconvolve')
    plt.xlabel('Signal length')
    plt.ylabel('Elapsed time in seconds')

    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()

    plt.show()
```

Comment: it will be faster in the future https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5608

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, `numpy.correlate` was designed for 1D arrays,  while `scipy.correlate` can accept ND-arrays.

The scipy implementation being more general and therefore complex, seem  indeed to incur an additional computational overhead. You can compare the C code between [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/588aff4847eaaec1b3192bf878dc515298b9fdcf/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L1149) and [scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/correlate_nd.c.src) implementations.

Another difference, could be for instance, that numpy implementation gets better vectorized by the compiler on modern processors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With a slightly updated code (see below) I get a very different picture than in 2015:
[Updated figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtlbm.png)

For array lengths >10^3 the SciPy implementation is consistently faster by up to roughly an order of magnitude.

The updated code:

```
import time

import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sps

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = 10**(np.arange(10)/2)
    a = a.astype(int)
    print(a)

    results = {}
    results['np.correlate'] = np.zeros(len(a))
    results['sps.correlate'] = np.zeros(len(a))
    results['sps.fftconvolve'] = np.zeros(len(a))

    ii = 0
    for length in a:

        sig = np.random.rand(length)

        t0 = time.process_time()
        for jj in range(3):
            np.correlate(sig, sig, 'full')
        t1 = time.process_time()
        elapsed = (t1-t0)/3

        results['np.correlate'][ii] = elapsed

        t0 = time.process_time()
        for jj in range(3):
            sps.correlate(sig, sig, 'full')
        t1 = time.process_time()
        elapsed = (t1-t0)/3

        results['sps.correlate'][ii] = elapsed

        t0 = time.process_time()
        for jj in range(3):
            sps.fftconvolve(sig, sig, 'full')
        t1 = time.process_time()
        elapsed = (t1-t0)/3

        results['sps.fftconvolve'][ii] = elapsed

        ii += 1

    ax = plt.figure()
    plt.loglog(a, results['np.correlate'], label='np.correlate')
    plt.loglog(a, results['sps.correlate'], label='sps.correlate')
    plt.loglog(a, results['sps.fftconvolve'], label='sps.fftconvolve')
    plt.xlabel('Signal length')
    plt.ylabel('Elapsed time in seconds')

    plt.legend()
```